# Apache Proxy both ssl and non-ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, https, proxy, openssl

Trying to configure the Apache to work as proxy for SSL and non-SSL and to be able to modify the response body (in my case pop-up alert on JS errors).
Something like that:

- HTTP <-> Apache Proxy (changing response) <-> Corporate Proxy <->
  Internet (HTTP)
- HTTPS <-> Apache Proxy (changing response) <->    Corporate Proxy <->
  Internet (HTTPS)

After strangling a bit I did it for the non-SSL Example:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://<corporate proxy>/
ProxyPassReverse / http://<corporate proxy>/
<IfModule substitute_module>
    AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE text/html
    Substitute "s|(<head.*?>)|$1<script type='text/javascript'>window.onerror=function(error){\n alert(error);\n};\n</script>|i"
</IfModule>
```

Sadly, I didn't mange to do the same for SSL... and the connection is failing to establish..
(I think something in the configuration or maybe in the understanding of how such proxy works)

From the httpd-ssl file:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass / http://<corporate proxy>/
ProxyPassReverse / http://<corporate proxy>/

SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/ssl/rootCA.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/ssl/rootCA.key"
```

To generate the certificate I run the next commands

Create the Root Key

```
openssl genrsa -out C:\Apache24\ssl\rootCA.key 2048
```

Self-sign this certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key C:\Apache24\ssl\rootCA.key -days 1024 -out C:\Apache24\ssl\rootCA.pem
```

I'm actually trying to replace ([Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)) which I configure it to Decrypt HTTPS, see screen shot in the link below

[Fiddler HTTPs Configuration](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS)

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you post your configuration for the SSL version?

Comment: Please note that I've managed to make the server work (both ssl and non-ssl) as a plain Server (I saw the "It works!" text). but as proxy... the SSL didn't work...

Comment: Don't have to be Apache proxy... could be any other configurable proxy server (that can handle SSL/non-SSL and modifying the response body)

Comment: Hmm, there are some things to address. Does the backend application have SSL? or is the SSL connection to end at the proxy? So as I see it you have 1: An application, 2: A reverse proxy for modifying response body, 3: A corporate proxy (caching? squid? etc.) <-> Client Browser. You want requests to go from the client to the corporate proxy to apache proxy to the application. What is your SSL endpoint? is the corporate proxy handling SSL at all? is the application?

Comment: @JacobMargason I wish that in the browser I'll be able to access to SSL web site (e.g. GitHub, https://github.com/) and to modify the response body.
So, the Apache Proxy should handle the SSL connection and to pass it to the corporate proxy (http, which will pass it as is) and then the SSL web-site. (and when I get response I'll be able to modify it so, I've to be a man-in-the-middle like) 
Is that answer your questions? :)

Comment: So you want to go From HTTPS > HTTP > HTTPS? I don't think that will work. Also if you have https://github.com in the browser and you handle SSL on your proxy you'll get an invalid certificate warning since you won't have the right key for the TLS negotiation. Unless of course you are using a different URL. Unless you are more specific about your needs I am not going to try and figure this out. This is kind of setup could be used as a phishing site. Breaking SSL between the end points negates the point of end to end encryption.

Comment: No planing for fishing... it's for testing only(I'm in a corporate netowrk). Yes I'll get an invalid certificate netowrk but I'm going to install the Apache key on each VM I'm using.    I'm wishing to replace Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as it become very slow when I access from several machines.

Comment: Okay, I'll set this up on my network this week. I'll see if I can make it work. just to be clear, we want the client to go to your reverse proxy via SSL, then to the corporate proxy via HTTP then from the corporate proxy to https://somesite.com, then back to the corporate proxy, then back to your proxy where you'll modify the response body, then finally back to the client. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @JacobMargason, not exactly. The client will establish SSL connection with the apache proxy and the apache proxy will establish connection with the server (i.e. somesite.com) the corporate proxy will pass the ssl connection as is (in other words will use CONNECT)

Comment: Okay, got it. I'll try to set something similar up when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's look that my configuration (working behind corporate proxy, need cascading proxy support) isn't supported by Apache.
And also this should not be reverse proxy but SSL forward proxy with termination... I didn't find any documentation on how to set it in Apache proxy.

So, until this will be supported by Apache, I suggest to close this thread.